# вычислить количество символов в строке

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Есть код:

```
SECTION .bss
        num:    resb 10

SECTION .data
        hello:  db 'Enter string: ',0
        helloLen: equ $-hello
        output: db 'String: ',0
        outputLen: equ $-output
        disbEnter: db '',10
        disbLen: equ $-disbEnter
SECTION .text
        GLOBAL _start

_start:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,hello
        mov edx,helloLen
        int 80h

        mov eax,3
        mov ebx,2
        mov ecx,num
        mov edx,10
        int 80h

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,output
        mov edx,outputLen
        int 80h

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx, num
        mov edx,10
        int 80h

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        call len

        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,disbEnter
        mov edx,disbLen
        int 80h

        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 80h
```

Мы вводим строку, надо при выводе вывести также её длину, то есть количество символов в ней.

Comment: Так разве sys_read не возвращает количество прочитанных байтов в EAX?

Comment: Это я понимаю, но не могу понять, как сохранить значение eax и вывести его @Akina

Comment: Если в EAX есть результат, зарезервируйте для него место, как сделано для строки и сохраните: mov [length],eax. При выводе строки, в edx указываете фактическую длину (как сделано при выводе приветствия) - для этого берете сохраненный length. Затем сделайте вывод искомой длины: ecx должен указать на сохраненное значение и так же, вызываете sys_write. Обратите внимание что call len - у вас ведет в никуда.